# How would Master of the Wild Hunt be worded if it targeted multiple creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, game-design

[Master of the Wild Hunt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Master%20of%20the%20Wild%20Hunt) says:

> [...] {T}: Tap all untapped Wolf creatures you control. Each Wolf tapped this way deals damage equal to its power to target creature. That creature deals damage equal to its power divided as its controller chooses among any number of those Wolves.

The way that MotWH works is that you choose a single target creature, and when it resolves you tap all untapped wolves you control and they deal damage to the single target creature amd that creature divides its damage among the wolves.

**How would you word the ability if you wanted each wolf to be able to target a different creature?**

**Does a template already exist for this functionality?**

For example [Raiding Party](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Raiding%20Party) allows you to choose plains (not exactly targeting)

> [...] Sacrifice an Orc: Each player may tap any number of untapped white creatures he or she controls. For each creature tapped this way, that player chooses up to two Plains. Then destroy all Plains that weren't chosen this way by any player.

and [Living Inferno](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Living%20Inferno) is only a single creature that is splitting its damage (the wolves would each target a single creature, but their might be multiple wolves)

> {T}: Living Inferno deals damage equal to its power divided as you choose among any number of target creatures. Each of those creatures deals damage equal to its power to Living Inferno.

Comment: @ikegami, I don't think a template exists either, but if it did it would be near official (so I included it). This card tripped me up when I first read it, I thought it targeted multiple creatures (living inferno also had some rules issues as well, if I remember right). If an approximate wording could be reached that wasn't ambiguous, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Say you target a 2/2 twice, a 3/3 once. How much damage would the new card deal back to the wolves? 2? 3? 5? 7?

Comment: @ikegami There's two options, both viable depending on the template: Option A) The two wolves that target the 2/2 can have 2 damage divided between the two as decided by the controller of the 2/2. The 3/3 deals 3 damage to the wolf that targeted it. Option B) The controllers of the 2/2 and the 3/3 divide the 2 and 3 damage among the three wolves as they choose. (By extension, if the 2/2 and 3/3 are owned by a single controller, he or she divides 5 damage among the three wolves as he or she chooses.)

Comment: @corsiKa, There are far more than those options. The question stands: Could the OP actually specify what he wants the new card to do?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is to change the operation slightly. Instead of having each wolf deal damage, have the lord deal damage.

> {T}: Tap all untapped Wolf creatures you control. ~ deals damage equal to the total power of those Wolves divided between up to X target creatures, where X is the number of Wolves tapped in this way. Those creatures deal damage equal to their power divided as their controllers choose among any number of those Wolves.

This would be a functional change, for example you could have a black wolf, like [Carion Howler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Carion%20Howler), and your opponent could have [Darkwatch Elves](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darkwatch%20Elves), who has protection from black, on the board. Under my change, the damage from the howler could be dealt to the elves. Currently, it couldn't (even though the Master does the targeting, the wolf does the damaging). I think the simplicity of it allows for such a sacrifice.

Comment: This isn't exactly right. "{T}: Tap all untapped Wolf creatures you control. Each Wolf tapped this way deals damage equal to its power to up to X target creatures" could be interpreted to mean that **each wolf** could deal damage to **each target**, I.e. 3x 2/2 wolfs could deal 6 damage to 3 targets.

Comment: @user1873 You're right. I've come up with something I think will work, but it does make a minor change. I think the number of instances where it would change the outcome of the effect is minimal.

Comment: Still has issues, it still sounds like you are dealing X damage to X creatures, instead of 2 (the normal power of the wolves) damage to up X target creatures. **maybe** this is the reason MotWH works the way it does.

Comment: @user1873 For whatever reason, my entire edit didn't show up. I'll either blame it on posting so late, or on my touchpad, which has been known to cause me to delete lines *grumble grumble*. Anyway, I added the appropriate text that was missing from last night.

Comment: Well done. Damage division is done at activation time, so bouncing can still reduce damage dealt. For me, this was a key factor in an acceptable answer. It's unfortunate that ~ doing damage has a detrimental effect on flavour, but a functional change is inevitable.